# TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.DOM is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Error when running basic react. something is wrong with the module

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () =>{
  return <div>
    <ul>
      <li>This is jeff</li>
      <li>This is not Jeef</li>
      <li>This is Joe</li>
    </ul>;
  </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.querySelector('#root'));
```

This is jeff
This is not Jeef
This is Joe

Answer (score 1):

Please wrap your return statement with "()" and run your code again.
Happy coding.